# R: Optimise spike pruning function

Tags: r, vectorization

Since I have not found an R package for analysis of electrophysiological data, I have used a function for spike pruning from my group:

```
prune.spikes <- function(spikes, min.isi) {
    # copy spike matrix
    prunedspikes <- spikes

    # initialise index of last spike: infinitely before the first one.
    for (i in 1:ncol(spikes)) {
        last <- -Inf
        for (j in 1:nrow(spikes)) {
            if (spikes[j, i] == 1) {
                if (j - last < min.isi) {
                    prunedspikes[j, i] <- 0;  # remove the spike
                }
                else {
                    last <- j
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    return(prunedspikes)
}
```

The function takes a spike vector or matrix consisting of 0 and 1 values and removes any 1 if it occurred within a minimum interval.
Because of the two nested loops it takes ages to run. In order to optimise it I have come up with this solution (removes one loop):

```
prune.cols <- function(spikes, min.isi) {
    prunedspikes <- apply(spikes, 2, FUN = prune.rows, min.isi = min.isi)
    return(prunedspikes)
}

prune.rows <- function(spikes, min.isi) {
    prunedspikes <- spikes
    last <- -Inf
    for (i in 1:length(spikes)) {
        if (spikes[i] == 1) {
            if (i - last < min.isi) {
                prunedspikes[i] <- 0;  # remove the spike
            }
            else {
                last <- i
            }
        }
    }
    return(prunedspikes)
}
```

Calling `prune.cols` on a large data set is noticeable faster compared to the original version (~60 times). One loop remains, though. So far I could not come up with a nice and simple solution. How can the function be even further improved?

Comment: Try `compiler` or implement in `Rcpp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Khashaa proposed, I implemented the function with the help of Rcpp:

```
NumericMatrix prunespikes(NumericMatrix spikes, double minisi) {
  NumericMatrix prunedspikes = spikes;
  int ncol = spikes.ncol();
  int nrow = spikes.nrow();
  for (int i = 0; i < ncol; i++) {
    int last = 0;
    while (spikes(last, i) == 0) {
      last++;
    }
    for (int j = last + 1; j < nrow; j++) {
      if (spikes(j, i) == 1) {
        if (j - last < minisi) {
          prunedspikes(j, i) = 0;
        } else {
          last = j;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return prunedspikes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the speed difference is not a problem yet, it may be better to keep the loop instead of using Rcpp.

According to Hadley Wickham's article [Loops that should be left as is](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#), it is not a bad idea to have this loop as it can be categorized into the *Recursive relationship* case.

Once the speed is the bottleneck, then resorting to Rcpp or [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) (suggested by the article too) may be the solution.